# Pass data through middleware or router in Express

Tags: node.js, express

I am developping a web service and I the server to manage the content negociation in term of language (Accept-Language). I don't know really how we do in Express. But I have done some code :

```
router.all('/*', (req, res, next) => {
  var enFrancais = true
  var languagesAsked = req.headers["accept-language"]
  languagesAsked = languagesAsked.split(',')
  var languages = []
  for (var languagesAsked of languagesAsked) {
    try {
      languages.push({language: languagesAsked.split(";")[0],
                      pref:     languagesAsked.split(";")[1].split("=")[1]})
    } catch(err) {
      languages.push({ language: languagesAsked, pref: "1"})
    }
  }
  _.sortBy(languages, "pref")
  if(!languages[0].language.startsWith('fr')) {
    enFrancais = false
  }
  next() //next(enFrancais) don't works. => ERR 500
});

router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  var APIconfiguration = {
  version: "0.1",
  baseUrl: "/api",
  date: new Date(),
  responseLanguage: enFrancais
  }
  res.send(APIconfiguration)
});
```

The first router return `true` if the `Accept-Language` header of the HTTP header says "I prefer French" or `false`if not.

I want in each call of the service that this router (or middleware if it has to be one) manage this HTTP header (to not write this code twice.)

Can I pass the data from the first part to the second part properly ?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: use `req.enFrancais` instead

Comment: That's working ! Thanks you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @alex-rokabilis for his answer.

I used req.myVariable to pass the data :)